# Why the ball is not going down when it crosses the edge i.e. gameover condition?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here the probgram is not updating with the line:rb.velocity = new Vector3 (0, -25f, 0); the ball suppose to fall down when it passes the edge but it stucks at the edge ..i also make zer0 friction between the edge and the ball..

```
void Start () {
    started = false;
    gameOver = false;
}

void Update () {

    if (!started) {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3 (speed, 0, 0);
            started = true;
        }
    }

    Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, Vector3.down, Color.red);

    if (!Physics.Raycast (transform.position, Vector3.down, 1f)) {
        gameOver = true;
        rb.velocity = new Vector3 (0, -25f, 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && !gameOver)
    {
        SwitchDirection ();
    }
}
void SwitchDirection(){
    if (rb.velocity.z > 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3 (speed, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (rb.velocity.x > 0){
        rb.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 0, speed);
    }

}
```

Comment: I've removed the following tags: `visual-studio` - this tag is intended for questions about the Visual Studio IDE, not about code you write using it. `monodevelop` - like Visual Studio, MonoDevelop is an IDE, so using the tag here would be incorrect for the same reason as the VS tag. `unityscript` - UnityScript is a progrmaming language in its own right, separate from C#. Your code appears to be C# so I have removed the other tag.

Comment: Try `transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down)` instead of `Vector3.down`?